# Retrieve a lost subversion repository

Tags: svn, copy, repository, caching

I have a Rails application working on Passenger deployed using Capistrano from a subversion repository. The subversion repository is lost. We just have a folder named "cached-copy" which I believe has been made by svn. Is it possible to recreate a subversion repository from this "cached-copy"?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.capify.org/index.php/Understanding_Deployment_Strategies

Comment: Thank you Moisei,
I went through the doc.
This helped me.
regards,
Sujith S

Comment: Sure. I am glad it helped. I would suggest you to make sure your repository always has an uptodate backup. It is really easy to implement using svn tools.